# Testing a CSV - how far should I go?

Tags: testing

I'm generating a CSV which contains several rows and columns.

However, when I'm testing said CSV I feel like I am simply repeating the code that builds the file in the test as I'm checking each and every field is correct.

Question is, is this more sensible than it seems to me, or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you building your expected strings in the test or simply stating them e.g. `string expected = "c,s,v";`?

Comment: Can you show an example of a test?

Comment: What are you "generating the CSV" from ? Objects that are read from a base, build using an API, etc... ? If so, then a test that builds the input to your "CSV Builder", get the output and compare it to a hard-written, expected CSV file seems more than sensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far simpler test is to just import the CSV into a spreadsheet or database and verify the data output is aligned to the proper fields. No extra columns or extra rows, data selected from the imported recordset is a perfect INTERSECT with the recordset from which the CSV was generated, etc.

More importantly, I recommend making sure your test data includes common CSV fail scenarios such as:

- Field contains a comma (or whatever your separator character)
- Field contains multiple commas (You might think it's the same thing, but I've seen one fail where the other succeeded)
- Field contains the new-row character(s)
- Field contains characters not in the code page of the CSV file

...to make sure your code is handling them properly.

Comment: Are you talking about looking at the actual file?  I'm writing tests that are automated.

Comment: No I mean use an automated process that imports the CSV file to, say, a SQL database, then uses queries to count the rows, count the columns, do an INTERSECT query against the original recordset, etc. Everything I said can be automated. Just because I'm foremost a DB guy, doesn't mean I don't know about test-driven development.  ;-)